# Extract sublevel domain from a list with Fully Qualified Domain Name addresses?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, scripting, extract

**Hello everyone,**

Using CMD/batch i'm trying to extract sub(or second)level domains from a self compiled (.txt) document with Fully Qualified Domain Name addresses in it.

**EXAMPLES**

```
FQDN address: www.somethingfunny.com
What i want : somethingfunny.com

FQDN address: something.funny.com
What i want : funny.com

FQDN address: www.somethingfunny.co.uk
What i want : somethingfunny.co.uk
```

Besides having searched/looked through and having tried other people's code, i have tried to FOR /F loop/iterate through the '.' periods, and hoped i could simply do this in a reverse/backwards search order. But, the more (failed) attempts i make and the longer i think about it, the more impossible it seems to pull this off (or atleast for me).

I am very aware there are much better solutions  (scripting/programming languages) to achieve this with, but does that also mean it's impossible to do such a thing using pure cmd/batch? I'm not sure!

**Lets find out...?**

(i know it can be of help to post some actual code, but i'm quite certain it will look like a complete mess/joke, set aside the fact that it would also embarras me... i'm happy to learn from others, though!)

Comment: Anything is possible in batch! (Not really but I have a solution stand by)

Comment: Hi John Kens. I can agree to that, but finding "the" way is a (true) challenge! I am curious what you will come up with. Thank you in advance for your time and patience! :-)

Comment: So something like `for /f  "tokens=1,* delims=." %a in (%_FQDN_%) set _secondLevel_=%*` should do it. Let me check...

Comment: BTW: How did you get so far without taking the [tour], reading [Ask], and [MCVE]?

Comment: Post your code or your question will probably be closed.

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm not completely sure what you are trying to say/point out. I know i'm not perfect and hope that this platform isn't just for tech savy (or perfect) people, but also for people who want to learn (more) about technical stuff. If my Question isn't qualified and/or lacking required information, then i'm really sorry about that. I have tried to explain the situation a clearly as possible. The code/script i'm working on however is (looking like) a real mess and exists of a mixture of different/incoherent code which isn't of any use to others (who probably know it a lot better than me).

Comment: A very common misconception is that this website is meant for learning. Instead, we are here to tell you why the code that you have isn't working. At the bare minimum, a question should have the code that you have written so far (it's fine that it doesn't work; if it worked, you wouldn't be here), what you expect the code to do, and what the code is actually doing. This is all explained on the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Comment: Yes, please just follow the links I provided and read the content. Then [Edit] your post. Often, you find your answers when you try to reduce your script down to a minimally complete and verifiable example. Occam's razor is a very sharp tool.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thanks you for the heads up, though (as i stated before), my code wouldn't even meet the lowest standards, as i'm lacking expertise. After having wasted many hours searching for answers, i don't find it strange to come to a point where you say "perhaps its better to get some actual help/feedback". I understand a question has to meet certain standards and that rules have to be made, but its not that i've never posted any code on here. It just often happens to be the case that my code sucks and me not wanting to make a fool/clown of myself.

Comment: I don't mind it that people know i can't code/script well, but sometimes i think it is better (read: more useful) to explain something with words, then to post a severely incomprehensible snippet of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on the command line: `for /f "tokens=1,* delims=." %a in ("%_FQDN_%") do set _secondLevel_=%b`. Double up on the '%' symbols in a batch file. Since you didn't bother to post an MCVE, I'll leave it to you to work out what the batch file should look like.

Comment: I don't know if this will work for all the examples that i gave, but i will definetely give it a swing. As soon as i've tried it i will let you know if it worked out. Thank you for thinking along with me, jwdonahue!

Comment: This actually works. Forgot tokens can use `*`. Congrats.

Comment: @JohnKens, I wouldn't have posted it, if it wasn't known to work, but it doesn't actually parse the input file format specified by the OP. They should have to do something useful, or they won't learn anything.

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm sorry to hear you say that but you don't know how much time i've spend and/or wasted on this particular case. Even if i posted "my" abysmal looking code, you wouldn't know, see, or understand how much effort i've taken to (try to) achieve what i want. I'm not the type of person who wants everything to be presented on a plate, without having tried anything myself, first..

Comment: Exactly! Because you didn't post an MCVE, we couldn't gauge where you were skills wise or whether you had actually put any effort into this problem at all. Read the links I provided in the comments to your OP.

Comment: Even though i've already done that when i signed up here, i'll read it all again.

Comment: My vote is in. The issue i was having (and always seem to be having) was related to the 'tokens' part. They never seem to give me the expected result, but your "one-liner" did the job for me! This really makes my day, err…night?... uh, no.. morning! (now you know how long this all has kept me busy/awake)..

Answer (score 2):

Now a `FOR` statement would be nice for your purpose and can be used in the following example bellow where `delims=.` will allow the statement to ignore those characters as spaces:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%G IN ("www.somethingfunny.com") do ECHO %%G %%H
```

By using `tokens=1*` or `tokens=1,*` you will process the first token and the 2nd + all subsequent items. More information on [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

```
@ECHO OFF

rem | Configure directories
set "input=C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\List.txt"
set "output=C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\new.txt"

rem | Loop through textfile and save to %output%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=." %%a in ('type "%input%"') do (echo %%b >> %output%)

goto :EOF
```

If anything credit goes to [jwdonahue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150445/jwdonahue) for reminding me the advanced use of the token system in statements. Hope I can at least educate you on the process.

Comment: I must say John Kens that i really appreciate the way how you explained everything to the smallest details. I thank you for this very reason and will try the code you've posted. If it happens to be a solution for my problem, i'll vote for your answer. I will also take note of how the code works. Again Thank You for caring about other people and have a good one! :-)

Comment: This has the advantage of removing the prefix "FQDN address:" from the input line, along with the first dotted field.  I personally prefer to avoid using multi-line code blocks in script file though.

Comment: John, I'll throw in an up-vote if you combine my example with yours, without using any multi-line code blocks. I suggest `call :Something`.

Comment: Both method's I listed work 100% and are true to it's nature. I personally forgot about the use of wildcards in the token system so @jwdonahue 's is smaller and more compact. I switched the code over to his idea. Thanks man for reminding me about it.

Comment: Ah, you posted it while typed!

Comment: Now that's pretty.

Comment: @script'n'code Just to make sure, `FQDN address: ` is not in the text file correct? If so I can revert my response to work with that.

Comment: @JohnKens, that should work. You set `delims=.`, so everything up to the first dot should wind up in %%a, which you are leaving for the bit-bucket collection.

Comment: Try it with the OP's original data in the file.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yeah I tested right after posting that. Seems to work just fine. The first part does get carried so everything is fine as `delims=.` takes care of the first `.`.

Comment: @JohnKens The text file only has domains in it. I'm about to test your (and jwdonahue)'s code. I'm barely finished reading all the comments (please bear with me).

Comment: @JohnKens (and jwdonahue): i've thrown a couple of thought up addresses to it. They all give the expected/wanted output, but example.co.uk resulted in co.uk, which doesn't appear to have an existing website. This isn't much of a problem since this specific TLD doesn't appear to occur often (or at all) in my list, but it can be problematic when encountering other variations of TLD's. I guess this can be overcome by adding the necessary workarounds. But all-in-all (and for the specific use-case), the given code works :-) Now, who gets the credit(s)? (there's only 'one' answer possible, right?)

Comment: a FYI: with 'example.co.uk', i was hoping to get the same output, since '.co.uk' often go together and i've never seen or encountered a website of which the url/domain ended on just '.uk'. The 'www.example.co.uk' address gives 'example.co.uk' as output, which is good. So only 'example.co.uk' as input seems to be a problem.

Comment: @script'n'code The code does exactly what you described you needed in your post. The `www.somethingfunny.co.uk` Turns into `somethingfunny.co.uk` So I'm unsure what your issue is. The script does not have the AI to determine if it's an ACTUAL valid domain. You might be able to use `ping` along with `%errorlevel%` along with an `if` statement to determine if it's already "Crop'd" or not. If that's what you needed you should update your post and use my response along side your attempt (Thus it's not a minimal complete question) and i'll be happy to help.

Comment: No worries, it IS a minimal complete question. While i was testing the code i was basically thinking out loud and wanted to inform you guys about my on-going progress. My OP question is what it is all about, i just happened to try some different ideas along the way. I've also placed my vote, but thank BOTH of you for solving this (little) mystery for me! :-)

Comment: My two-cents: @JohnKens did more work than I did, he should get the official answer, if it's not too late to change it. His original concept worked fine and he was willing to incorporate my suggestion. It's not like any of us actually invented any of these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to tldextract, this will output the different component host & subdomain, domain, TLD:

```
cat file | while read fqdn; do tldextract $fqdn ; done
```

Just domain and TLD for example:

```
cat file | while read fqdn; do tldextract $fqdn | cut -d " " -f 2,3 ; done
```